# My Places API returns 'ZERO_RESULTS'

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

My site shows Gmap with few places categories (cafe, pharmacy. bank, etc...)
Some categories ALWAYS returns 'ZERO_RESULTS' while Only two returns results.

Here is an example for a good request-
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/PlaceService.FindPlaces?1m6&1m2&1d32.0644854235794&2d34.78186263896919&2m2&1d32.073468576420595&2d34.79246336103074&2siw&6sparking&callback=_xdc_._pocujy&token=76152`

Here is an example for a bad request-
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/PlaceService.FindPlaces?1m6&1m2&1d32.0644854235794&2d34.78186263896919&2m2&1d32.073468576420595&2d34.79246336103074&2siw&6sbank&callback=_xdc_._g07omw&token=49745`

As you can see the 'bad' request returns this-

`_xdc_._g07omw && _xdc_._g07omw( {
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"`
}
 )

- The answer is ZERO for any location on my map (Israel Map)
- The Places do exist and should appear (like in maps.google.co.il)

Do you have an idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is most likely the fact that Google hasn't yet added the actual categories (`types`) to all the places in its database. So, for example, a place which you actually know that it should return with `"types" : [ "cafe", "restaurant", "establishment" ]`, it will return instead with only `"types" : [ "establishment" ]`.

So, until the missing `types` are included, a less-precise workaround might be filtering those categories by `name` or `keyword` parameter, which might increase the chances of returning (at least some) relevant results.

Comment: Can i learn from your answer that Google is using the types "establishment" as a default/replacement until it really indexing a type?

Comment: @user2302794 Yes, that's what I meant. You can check some of the related questions and you'll see that this is an issue experienced by many users here on SO.