# Can't see places I have added - Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I've added some places using the Google Places API and then searched for them but I am getting no responses. The Google Places API Docs state that any places you add yourself are immediately available to your own app.

code used to ADD the place:

```
$content = '{
"location": {
"lat": 55.9924222,
"lng": -4.5767703
},


"accuracy": 50,
  "name": "MYPLACE",
   "types": ["other"],
  "website": "http://example.com",
  "language": "en-GB"
}';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key=MYKEY');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
$json_response = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 201 ) {
    die("response $json_response");
};


curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($json_response);
```

The JSON response:

```
{  
   "id":"f9f16c68e531d8fc583e9d6b321f91d3f4aee41b",
   "place_id":"qgYvCi0wMDAwMDA2NTdhZjZiZTc5OjQ4ODg1MzIzOTc1OmZmOTA3OTI1MWEwOTdlYjI",
   "reference":"CkQxAAAAXR8NXJss0Mkw79jPrfLSDfDV8v9n94HmuZsN5pPdvSp5D8gLlBlVvXdTHqJlAq6larv-asoMF22gc6vonSVM8xIQtYSx9WMivS9eI6MsrQuiMhoUtlAGv0nDCEAF-5lphcVBbO4CI-U",
   "scope":"APP",
   "status":"OK"
}
```

Then I search using:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=55.9859890,-4.5723500&radius=5000&type=other&keyword=getfed&key=MYKEY
```

and the response:

```
{
  "html_attributions": [],
  "results": [],
  "status": "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Could anyone give me any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

[`ZERO_RESULTS`](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchStatusCodes) indicates that the search was successful but returned no results. This may occur if the search was passed a latlng in a remote location.

You can see in this [page](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/faq) the possible reasons why you can't see the places you have added. It's possible that the place you are looking for has not yet been categorized. All places are categorized as the generic type `establishment` until Google has enough data about a place to categorize it as one of the [supported place types](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types).

You may check this reference:

- [My Places API returns 'ZERO_RESULTS'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123878/my-places-api-returns-zero-results)

  > The reason for this behavior is most likely the fact that Google hasn't yet added the actual categories to all the places in its database.

Another possible reason based on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place).

> When you add a place, the new place is available immediately in Nearby Searches initiated by your application. The new place also enters a moderation queue to be considered for Google Maps. **A newly-added place does not appear in Text Search or Radar Search results, or to other applications, until it has been approved by the moderation process.**

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but I think you haven't understood the documentation. The excerpt you've pasted in says "When you add a place, the new place is available immediately in Nearby Searches initiated by your application". The section you have highlighted in bold refers to the place appearing generally in Google Maps for regular users. I am trying to access the place via my own app, which should be able to see the place immediately after being added.

Comment: From the FAQ page: "How can I create custom places?

If you would like to add places that are immediately available to your application, you can perform a Place Add request which will give your applications instant access to the newly added place via your Google API Console key."